# Is it possible to use "Runtime.addBinding" of CDP method two times in only one CDP Session?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol, cdp

I need to investigate two functions in different "bindingCalled" event. I want to learn whether it is possible?

Comment: If it's possible there'll be no special trick for this. If it's not then it's not.

Comment: After trying to listen two events with different names, I was able to get them with "bindingCalled" listener.

Comment: @AsumanSenol can you provide an example?